# How to prove that $\{x\in E: h(x)>d\}$ is open and $\{x\in E : \varphi_\beta(x)=d \mbox{ for all } x\in A\}$ is closed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $h:\varphi_{\beta}:E\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous Where $\beta=A$ and $d\in\mathbb{R}$

How to prove that $\{x\in E: h(x)>d\}$ is open and $\{x\in E : \varphi_\beta(x)=d \mbox{ for all } x\in A\}$  is closed

Please show this more explanatory because I cannot understand the question. I want to learn. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you understand what open, closed and continuous mean?

Comment: Hmm on $\Bbb R^{n}$ space I understand definitions. But I cannot use in a question. Please. Can you show how to solve this step by step. If I see an example, I may be able to apply to other questions. Thank you. @copper.hat

Comment: I don't understand your response?

Comment: Sorry since I write wrong, i need to edit two times

Comment: If a function $f$ is continuous, and the set $C$ is closed, what can you say about $f^{-1}(C)$? Similarly, if the set $U$ is open, what can you say about $f^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: Hmm then this is relatively open for the set U.and this is relatively closed for the set C. Right? @copper.hat

Comment: Yes, notice that $\{x \in E | h(x) >d \} = h^{-1}((d,\infty))$ and the set $(d,\infty)$ is open. Similarly for the other set, since $\{d\}$ is a closed set, the inverse image with $\phi_\beta$ is also closed.

Comment: Hmm I cannot imagine this in my mind now. Is this All answer enough to explain that question?  @copper.hat

Comment: Ok! I understand now. Thank you :) @JasperLoy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\varphi_\beta$ is continuous and $\{d\}$ is closed, $\varphi_\beta^{-1}\{d\}$ is closed.

Since $h$ is continuous and $(d,+\infty)$ is open, $h^{-1}(d,+\infty)$ is open.

Comment: Minor point: The second function should be $h$.